# LWC dual listbox value from database

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-duallistbox

I am using a dual listbox to show account source fields. When selected and it is saving the value correctly. I want to use the same dual listbox for edit. The value from database is coming as a single argument. How I can prepopulate the dual listbox with this value as selected. I am new to salesforce and trying simple assigning the value to selectedItems but it is not working.

```
    <lightning-dual-listbox data-id="accountSource" 
                                                    id="accountSource" 
                                                    name="accountSource"  
                                                    selected-label="Selected" 
                                                    source-label="Available" 
                                                    options={sourcePicklistvalues} 
                                                    value={selectSource}
                                                    onchange={handleOnChange}>
                          </lightning-dual-listbox>
```

in js

```
this.selectedSource = detail.Account_Source__c ? detail.Account_Source__c.map(item => ({ label: item, value: item })) : ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are saved as colon(";") seperated string. And since `dual-list-box` takes value as a list. You will have to split the value to pre-populate it.

```
getAccount({ recordId : this.recordId }).then(result =>{
        this.selectedSource = result.Account_Source__c?.split(';') ?? [];
})
```

Comment: Sorry not working

Comment: my bad.. it should  be having just the values in array.